# Is there a better way to reference the indices (coordinates) of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, iterator, coordinates, indices

I'm looking to find a vectorised way to create ndarrays from formulae, using the indices (or coordinates) of the value being calculated.

For example, if I want a 4x5x3 array filled by the formula 3x+y^z, I have no current way to reference x, y, or z directly. The closest I can come to that is wasting memory by creating incrementing arrays through arange().

Here are my current methods:

```
import numpy as np


# for loops

arr = np.empty((4, 5, 3))
for x in range(4):
    for y in range(5):
        for z in range(3):
            arr[x, y, z] = 3 * x + y ** z
print(arr)


# separate arange()-created arrays for x, y, and z

x = np.arange(4)[:, None, None]
y = np.arange(5)[None, :, None]
z = np.arange(3)[None, None, :]
arr = 3 * x + y ** z
print(arr)


# same thing but written in a different way (I think)

all = np.arange(5)
arr = 3 * all[:4, None, None] + all[None, :, None] ** all[None, None, :3]
print(arr)
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this? I'm assuming there is, because numpy's underlying C code must use an iterator to find the memory addresses of each item, so surely that iterator could be repurposed as a faster alternative to using indices stored in memory?

Comment: Your `x,y,z` approach is good `numpy`.  I don't see what waste of memory you are talking about.  `numpy` is like playing with legos. It is fastest easiest is to work with the pieces in the set.  You don't worry about wasted material or space inside the blocks.

Comment: `x` `y` `z` have a total of 12 elements.   `arr` has 60.

Comment: (For context this reply was before I edited in the first example code.) I was under the impression that using arange() would allocate and use memory. If that's optimised to not involve memory, then that's good, but surely it still avoids using the iterator that C would be using?

Comment: Yes `arange(5)` makes a 5 element array.  `range` is an iterator, and doesn't use memory.  So?  But in `3 * x + y ** z`, the arrays don't have to be `[0,1,2,...]`.  They could be large arrays of floats, and not just 1d - provided you get the broadcasting dimensions right.  In the first case that would be equivalent to doing `3 *x[i] + y[j]**z[k]` where `i,j,k` are the range iterators.

Comment: Note that for evaluating a function on a grid of indices there is `np.fromfunction`. I wouldn't be too surprised if under the hood it did more or less what your code is doing.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, `fromfunction` confuses people.  It just uses `np.indices` to generate all the index arrays and then passes them (`*args`) to the function.  That's an array version of `meshgrid` (non-sparse).